# Display hours/rows issue with Kendo Scheduler and CRM 2013

Tags: css, telerik, dynamics-crm-2013, kendo-scheduler

I'm trying to integrate Kendo Scheduler with CRM 2013, so far did prepare data in the way that scheduler expects. It seems to work somehow but there is a problem in displaying hours as illustrated in following image:

[image: crm 2013 and events displaying issue]

It shows 9:30 am event in the row of 8 AM

A similar issue has been addressed
[HERE](http://www.telerik.com/forums/display-issues) and I believe my problem is also related to the host(Microsoft dynamics CRM 2013) css conflicts with kendo's css.
Anybody knows how can I fix this problem preferably supported way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who may come across this issue, I managed this problem without any further insights into CRM 2013 style definitions for tables by simply setting following style for my webresource:

```
<style> 
table {
  border-collapse: separate !important;
  margin-top: 0.00em !important;}
th{overflow:hidden;border-style:solid;border-width:0 0 1px 1px;padding:.5em .6em .4em .6em;font-weight:normal;white-space:nowrap;text-overflow:ellipsis;text-align:left !important;}
</style>
```

Hope it helps someone out there!